# SpringSecurity with database in vaadin maven project

Tags: spring, postgresql, vaadin

I have a vaadin maven project witch I integrate in spring security so I am able to see the default login form of spring security .
Now I want to get users from postgres database can you help me please? have you any tuto or books?

Comment: I do have a working example of an application using Vaadin + Spring Boot + Spring Security, but unfortunately this example goes without any documentation yet. But maybe you can get some inspiration from the code for your task: https://github.com/rolandkrueger/vaadin-by-example/tree/master/en/architecture/SpringBootSecurity

Comment: Thank you , I am going to see it

Comment: Please RolandKrüger , where is the configuration of the database in this example?

Comment: There is no explicit database configuration for this example, since I'm using the default Spring Boot settings and an in-memory database (hsqldb). In that case, Spring Boot uses an implicit DB configuration. An explicit configuration would take place in `application.properties`. Refer to the Spring Boot documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

As example (respecting Roland Krügers example) for Spring Boot Application + SpringSecurity + Vaadin4Spring # Hibernate, you have to define the following properties in application.properties:

```
# DATASOURCE
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myDB
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypwd
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.xa.data-source-class-name=org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
spring.datasource.pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection="true"

# one transaction manager via view
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
# for mapping models and attributes to table names and column names
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jta.default-transaction-timeout=2000
```

Using application.properties in your app add the following annotation to your main class:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
})
```

Now an entity of a user can look like:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LOGGED_IN")
    private boolean loggedIn;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }
}
```

After that you have to define a repository interface for Hibernate:

```
/**
*Spring auto repository for database access of User objects.
**/
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findOneByName(String userName);
}
```

Now you can do something like that in your login method:

```
...
vaadinSecurity.login(userName.getValue(), passwordField.getValue());
Optional<User> ouser = userRepository.findOneByName(userName);
if (ouser.isPresent()) {
    User user = ouser.get();
    user.setLoggedIn(true);
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander but please what about vaadinSecurity ? what is it? thank you

Comment: `VaadinSecurity` comes from the vaadin4spring repository [link](https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring). This offers some nice services like I18N, security and others. Have a look on [link](https://vaadin.com/web/petter/home/-/blogs/experimenting-with-vaadin-spring-and-serialization?_33_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fvaadin.com%2Fweb%2Fpetter%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3D33%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_pos%3D2%26p_p_col_count%3D3) how vaadin4spring is designed to use. There are also some samples inside.

Comment: I tried to configure spring security with vaadin and spring boot and I use SecurityConfig.java not xml file my problem now that I want to crate my custom login view but I can't , still now I have the default form login of spring have you any idea?

Comment: For an own login page you can do something like:

`@SpringUI(path = "/login")
@Theme("YourTheme")
public class LoginUI extends UI {
    
    private TextField userName;
    private PasswordField passwordField;
    private Button login;
    
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
         FormLayout loginForm = new FormLayout();
  loginForm.setSizeUndefined();

         loginForm.addComponent(userName = new TextField("Username"));
  loginForm.addComponent(passwordField = new PasswordField("Password"));
  loginForm.addComponent(login = new Button("Login"));
    }
}`

Comment: But I think, that is another question for stackoverflow.